# Split a string into a list in django-templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Basically, I have a colon delimited variable being passed into my template that I would like to loop through to display each individual element.

I would like to be able to extract each of these names and then perform logic on them within my template.

If I could use python, I would do something like (note: file_type is the variable I have in my template):

```
file_type = "PDF:DOC:XLS"
for tipe in file_type.split(":"):
   if tipe == "PDF":
      print "<img src='pdf'/>"
   elif tipe == "DOC":
      print "<img src='doc'/>"
   elif tipe == "XLS":
      print "<img src='xls'/>"
   else:
      print "<img src='unrecognized'/>"
```

So basically, is there a split function in django-templates or has anyone come up with a crafty way to do this? I haven't been able to find anything. Thanks!

Comment: can you register a filter and call split in the filter?  see http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/211/  also http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/889/

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This will be my first custom tag and I'm having a little difficulty with it, especially given I've been put on a project to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for a custom template tag or filter. If you ever find yourself thinking "If I could use Python here", that's the sign you need a custom tag/filter. You can more or less use the code you give above, just return the value instead of printing it.

Comment: Sure, steal my thunder ;)  (of course, I could have moved my comment to the answer, I'm just pulling your chain)

Answer (score 0):

split is not available as a filter in Django, however, you can create it and it will do exactly what you want. This is an example of what you need to do;

In views.py

from django.template.defaulttags import register

```
@register.filter(name='split')

def split(value, key): 

    value.split("key")
    return value.split(key)
```

in your html page, use your split filter as follows:

```
{% with file_type|split:":" as types %}
    {% for type in types %} 
        {{ type }}،                        
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

sources:
https://gist.github.com/linuxkathirvel/8127c40fdad028bbb79bec24f36eee1c